# Why is my function not changing my mocked state?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock my app's store and then alter a value in the mocked store for a unit test, but it seems like nothing is changing in my mocked store. All of the solutions that I've found are using this pattern/method of mocking the state and altering the value in the state so I'm lost as to why it isn't working for me.

Here is my unit test:

```
import {store} from "../../app/store/Store";
import {getUrlBuilder} from "../../app/utils/UrlUtils";

describe('Url Utils', () => {  
  beforeAll(() => {   
    jest.mock("../../app/store/Store", () => ({
      state: {
        auth: {
          isUSUser: false,
        }
      }
    }));  
  });

  describe('getUrlBuilder', () => {
    const path = "test/path";
    
    it('should return the correct url when the user is not a US user', () => {
      const expected = "https://www.website.cn/test/path";
      expect(getUrlBuilder({path})).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the function that I'm testing:

```
import {store} from "@store/Store";

const {getState} = store;

export const getUrlBuilder = ({
  subdomain = "www",
  path = "",
}: {
  subdomain?: string;
  path?: string;
}): string => {
  const state = getState();
  return state.auth.isUSUser ? `https://${subdomain}.website.com/${path}` : `https://${subdomain}.website.cn/${path}`;
};
```

UPDATE: Per the discussion below, this is my latest code for the unit test; unfortunately, I'm now getting the error about the `store` being undefined again:

```
import {store} from "../../app/store/Store";
import {getUrlBuilder} from "../../app/utils/UrlUtils";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const UserMockStore = {
  auth: {
    isUSUser: true,
  }
}

const middlewares = [createSagaMiddleware()];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const mockUserStore = mockStore(UserMockStore);

jest.mock("../../app/store/Store", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  store: mockUserStore,
}));  
...
```

Comment: jest.mock is hoisted above import only at top level. It's impossible to mock it like that when it's inside beforeAll because original module has already been imported at this moment. Move it outside.

Comment: @EstusFlask But if it's hoisted above the import, won't the value in `jest.mock` become undefined? I've tried having it outside under all my import statements, but then it seems that `store` becomes undefined when I run my unit test

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The value inside jest.mock factory function is a value that import will become equal to, not the opposite way. This will happen only if jest.mock is evaluated before import, but putting jest.mock inside beforeAll block prevents it from being hoisted.

Comment: @EstusFlask Hm I see, so I've tried moving the mock to outside of the `beforeAll` and under my import statements, but it seems like `store` is undefined when I run my test :( What could be the possible causes of the store being undefined?? It should be evaluating `jest.mock` before the import statements now so I'm a bit lost...:(

Comment: jest.mock provides CommonJS export by default, which translates to ESM `default` import. Should be `jest.mock("../../app/store/Store", () => ({ __esModule: true, state : ...`

Comment: Hm, tried the suggestion but still getting that the `store` is undefined, specifically, the error happens on this line: `const {getState} = store;` and the error message reads: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined`

Comment: It's `store` in one place and `state` in another.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, just curious, but what would you consider to be the cleanest fix for this? I'm trying a few different things out, but it'd be helpful to know what someone else's thoughts

Comment: It's `jest.mock("../../app/store/Store", () => ({ __esModule: true, store : ...` instead of `state` at top level.

Comment: @EstusFlask Hm, not sure if I need to open a new question for this, but it seems that I get this error message now: `TypeError: getState is not a function`; could it be that when I make my mock store, I need to use `configureMockStore`?

Comment: You can use configureMockStore or add getState manually, any way if it's expected that there's store.getState, you need to provide it in your mock.

Comment: @EstusFlask Gotcha, hm...let me update my question with my latest code; I tried using `configureMockStore`, but now it's saying that the `store` is undefined again :(

Comment: Ah I think I see why it's undefined, because `jest.mock` is hoisted to the top, I believe that `mockUserStore` will be undefined

Comment: Yes, it will. require configureMockStore inside jest.mock factory function.